# private STL self destruction when instance of class was destucrt?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I wonder, if i have an instance of a class, and a private pointer to a queue or avector, when the instance is being destructed, does the STL will be detruct too or do I need to delete[] it??
Moreover, if I have a private pointer to queue/vector, containing pointers to some object instace, if all the instances to which the pointer points was destructed, what happend to the queue/vetor?

Comment: Do you hold the container by value or pointer?

Comment: pointer :) @StoryTeller

Comment: Then nothing will happen automatically. It's no different to holding a `int` by pointer. And just like an `int`, it's pointelss to hold it by pointer. Those containers have value semantics for a reason.

Comment: I can assure you that private has nothing to do with anything here.

Comment: the private is really not the issue here, just a sample .. @juanchopanza

Comment: Don’t use pointer for vector or queue. You have to `delete` whatever you `new` exactly once.

Comment: thank friend ! @manni66